# API Returning The connection is not secure. API requests must be made via HTTPS

Tags: bigcommerce

We are getting the following error while trying to read some product details:

400The connection is not secure. API requests must be made via HTTPS.

URL We are calling IS over https:
https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/[removed]/v2/orders?page=1&limit=50

Thoughts?

Comment: How are you calling this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call https://store-XXXXXXXXX.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/orders to get the order details

(This method uses Basic authentication  and you have to replace the store name with your store name)